# Setting up PIN using Command Prompt Admin

Tags: security, windows-10

I have a question. I was poking around the security section of Windows 10, and saw the PIN option. Is there a way to set up a PIN using Command Prompt Admin? If so, can you please provide the command for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only reset a PIN code with that command:

```
icacls C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Ngc /T /Q /C /RESET
```

To set a normal password is possible with:

```
net user pcname P@ssw0rd1
```

To change the PIN through CMD or Powershell isn't possible, yet with simple commands.
Hope that answered your question! :)